# How to apply for a Japanese visa without an Indian tax return statement?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, japan

I just recently started working 6 months back (in India), so I have only bank statement but no ITR as I will get the first ITR at the end of accounting year. I am scheduled to fly on March 12, 2016.

How should I proceed for acquiring tourist visa for Japan?

Comment: Yeah I am going. Already booked the tickets

Comment: What does "ITR" mean?

Comment: Oh that means an Income Tax Return statement.

Comment: Since I started working in July only. I will get my first statement after March

Comment: The fact that you already booked the tickets does not necessarily mean you are going, especially if you do not have your visa yet. Contact the embassy or consulate where you plan to submit you application, they are the only ones who know the rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you are an Indian national.

According to the [Ministry of Foreign Affairs of Japan](http://www.mofa.go.jp/j_info/visit/visa/short/other_visa.html) in a [document which outlines the application procedure for Nationals of India](http://www.mofa.go.jp/files/000121950.pdf), you can use an Income certificate or bank statement:

> **1. Eligibility for Applicant**
>   Nationals of India with ordinary MRP (Machine Readable Passport) / e-passport in compliance with the ICAO
>   (International Civil Aviation Organization) standard, who wishes to apply for a Multiple Visa for a stay of up to
>   30 days and are applicable to one of the following categories:
>
> (1) Individual who has travel record as temporary visitor to Japan in the last three years and who has ability to pay the travel expense
>
> (2) Individual who has travel record as temporary visitor to Japan and travel records as temporary visitor to G7 countries (except Japan) in the last three years
>
> ***(3) Individual with sufficient financial capacity***
>
> (4) Spouse or children of the individuals who are mentioned (3) above
>
> **2. Necessary Documents to Submit**
>   ...
>   (3) Applicant with sufficient financial capacity (as mentioned 1(3) above)
>
> a. Application form (with Photo)
>   b. Passport (MRP / e-passport in compliance with the ICAO standard only)
>   ***c. Documents to prove the sufficient financial ability such as income certificate, bank statement, or
>   income tax return (and some additional documents which certify incomes such as stock dividend, pension, retirement allowance, inheritance, lease agreement, real estate register, deed of property etc.)***
>   d. Applicant’s Certificate of employment
>   e. A letter of explanation stating the reason of applying for the multiple visa
>   (f. if applying from outside of India) documents to prove that the applicant legally resides in that country

If you go through the entire document, you should have all that you need to submit an application for a visa.  Good luck.

Comment: Hey but this is for someone with travel record to Japan in the last years. I will be travelling for the first time.

Comment: @AbKDs sorry I had the wrong section copied in.  see 1.(3) also I have copied in the right section now, and added emphasis on the relevant text

Comment: also see http://www.in.emb-japan.go.jp/short_term%20visas.html